# How to delete other people's Gmail profile picture?

Tags: gmail, photos, delete

I do not want to see other's photos when I enter their address to send them an email.

How to delete their avatar?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your contacts and find the contact in question.
2. Click on the current avatar (their profile picture)... "Change Picture".
3. Select "No Photo".
4. Click "Set as contact photo".

You can change it back again by repeating steps 1 & 2 and selecting "Profile photo".